# Do I have to set a default value to a variable in Twig

Tags: theming

Normally in php I would have to set a default value to a variable but in Twig do I have to set a default value?

```
{% if content.my_field|render %}
  {% set offset = content.my_field['#items'].getString() %}
{% endif %}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes).setAttribute('data-offset', offset) }}>
```

I think it works but not sure if I should do this:

```
{% set offset = ''  %}
{% if content.my_field|render %}
  {% set offset = content.my_field['#items'].getString() %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's controlled by a Twig environment setting, [`strict_variables`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#environment-options):

> If set to false, Twig will silently ignore invalid variables (variables and or attributes/methods that do not exist) and replace them with a null value. When set to true, Twig throws an exception instead (default to false).

Drupal doesn't change the default value, so if you also leave that setting at `false` you won't need to make sure variables exist before referencing them. In fact, if you set it to `true` I imagine quite a few core and contrib would start throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect no since our variable is set only IF the rendered field has value.

Comment: Say it never goes inside the if statement, offset is never created.  In PHP this would cause a warning.  In Twig it might be okay I'm assuming.